# How to properly use NLog in ASP.NET CORE application with Autofac as a dependency container?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, autofac, nlog

In my ASP.NET CORE application I use Autofac as a dependency container and NLog for logging.
I register NLog in Autofac like:

```
builder.Register(x => 
        {
            var config = x.Resolve<IConfigurationRoot>();
            return new NLogLogger(config);

        }).As<ILogger>();
```

Class NlogLogger looks like:

```
public class NLogLogger : IT.CORE.LoggingCore.ILogger
{
    private NLog.ILogger logger;


    public NLogLogger(IConfigurationRoot configuration)
    {
        logger = LogManager.Setup()
                   .LoadConfigurationFromSection(configuration)
                   .GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }


    public void Debug(Exception exception)
    {
        logger.Debug(exception);
    }

    // the rest of the login methods
    ...
}
```

In application I inject via constructor ILogger and use appropriate method for logging.

In NLog documentation we can see:
[image: NLog best practices]

How do you register and use NLog in your projects as a static private field in each class or resolve it from DI Container ?

Comment: Guess the tutorial should says that the advice about `static Logger`-should be ignored when using dependency-injection. But still good advice to cache the Logger in the constructor.

Comment: But be careful with loading the NLog-config in the `NLogLogger`-constructor, unless you promise to have the `NLogLogger` as singleton-lifetime.